# Compare strings and just keep those who have on same positions different characters

Tags: regex, python-2.7

my question is the following: I have a file which contains around 70 strings, all of them have 6 characters (either a,c,g or t for every position -> these are short DNA-sequences).

For example:

```
accggt agctta gggatc gactta ccttgg
```

What I need are the strings which are completely unique. Which have on every position a different character (base) compared with the other strings.

In this case I would get two matches (I define them as lists but this is only an idea for the output format):

```
[accggt , gggatc]
[gggatc , ccttgg]
```

The elements of list one are on every position different and so are also the elements of list 2.

Is there a build-in function which can do it? I also thought of regular expression but I'm not that familar with this approach.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Ok, it seems it is not that easy to describe. So lets go into more detail:
Let's take the five strings mentioned above:

I would start to compare the first string with all the other strings and then continue with string 2 comparing with all other strings and so on.

The first character of the first string is an a.
The first character of the second string is also an a.
This means I would discard the second string.

The first character of the third string is an g.
Fine.
The second character of the first string is an c.
The second character of the third string is an g.
Fine.
The third character of the first string is an c.
The third character of the third string is an g.
Fine.
The fourth ... and so on.

And if all characters of a string are different from the characters of another string (on every position like described above) I would keep those two strings and would search for the next strings which are different on every position compared to the strings I already found. Because I only have four letters there should be only four possibilities fo different strings.

I should end up with, probably a list, which contains the groups of strings which are different in every position.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in function to do that. But what I don't understand is the ***different character on every position***. Because `accggt` and `agctta` do both have a `c` at the third position. So it would not be different as you described. Please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Ah you mean the occurrence count of each character?

Comment: Please check [my demo](https://ideone.com/XQVsB4). Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: @stribizhev That's it. Thanks a lot. Perfect!!!!

Comment: @Tobias: I posted that as an answer.

Comment: This is not a too broad question, just the description of the task was not clear from the beginning, but it is cleared out in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm: iterate through all possible word combinations in your string and check each pair for equality with `if [x == y for (x, y) in zip(word, nextWord)].count(True) == 0:`.

Here is a snippet:

```
s = "accggt agctta gggatc gactta ccttgg"
chks = s.split(" ");
for word in chks:
    for nextWord in chks:
        if word != nextWord:
            if [x == y for (x, y) in zip(word, nextWord)].count(True) == 0:
                print([word, nextWord])
```

Result of the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XQVsB4):

```
['accggt', 'gggatc']
['gggatc', 'accggt']
['gggatc', 'ccttgg']
['ccttgg', 'gggatc']
```

**UPDATE**

You can deduplicate the list with a custom function. Here is an updated snippet:

```
def dedup(lst):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        fs = frozenset(item)
        if fs not in seen:
            result.append(item)
            seen.add(fs)
    return result

res = []
s = "accggt agctta gggatc gactta ccttgg"
chks = s.split(" ");
for word in chks:
    for nextWord in chks:
        if word != nextWord:
            if [x == y for (x, y) in zip(word, nextWord)].count(True) == 0:
                res.append([word, nextWord])


print(dedup(res))
```

Result: `[['accggt', 'gggatc'], ['gggatc', 'ccttgg']]`.

To check the words by 3, you need to create all possible permutations of the string into 3-word combinations and use something like:

```
from itertools import permutations

def dedup(lst):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        fs = frozenset(item)
        if fs not in seen:
            result.append(item)
            seen.add(fs)
    return result

res = []
s = "accggt agctta gggatc gactta ccttgg"
chks = s.split(" ");

perms = [p for p in permutations(chks, 3)]

for perm in perms:
    if [(x == y or y == z or x == z) for (x, y, z) in zip(*perm)].count(True) == 0:
        res.append(perm)


print(dedup(res))
```

Comment: Ok, this is very close. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to adapt the code in a way that one would get three or four combinations? In my example there are only two strings per combination possible but my file has 70 different sequences and so there are some combinations with 3 or even 4 strings possible.

Comment: Do you mean to check 3 words at a time? Right now, the code is checking 2 words at a time.

Comment: Yes, exactly, three or even four words. I adapted the code and it worked so far. Is it possible to prevent from printing doubled or more occuring combinations. In your example above I would only need list 1 and 3 or 2 and 4 and so on.

Comment: To check 3 or 4 words at a time you can use something like `if [(x == y or y == z or x == z) for (x, y, z) in zip("cccggg", "aaattt", "tttaaa")].count(True) == 0:
 print("true")`. To remove duplicate tuples, use a custom `dedup` function as [is shown here](https://ideone.com/blmLJ6). Answer will be updated, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code does the the trick exactly as I need it.

Answer (score 0):

To find the DNA strings which are completely different on every character you have to check every **string** against any other **string** if any **character** of the given **string** is the same **character** on the same position in the comparing **string**.

Here is an example code for that:

```
# read all dna strings into a list of strings
dna = ['accggt', 'agctta', 'gggatc', 'gactta', 'ccttgg', '123456']

def compare_two_dna(dna1, dna2):
    i = 0
    l = len(dna1)

    while(i < l):
        if dna1[i] == dna2[i]:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False

def is_dna_unique(d, dna_strings):
    return len(filter(lambda x: compare_two_dna(d, x), dna_strings)) == 1

# filter all items which only occure once in the list
unique_dna = filter(lambda d: is_dna_unique(d, dna), dna)

print(unique_dna)
```

The result here is: `123456`

Comment: Yeah, this is close but unfortunately ccttgg[4] is equal to accggt[4] (the g) and so I would discard either the first or the third string.

Comment: That's why I asked you to clarify the **different character on every position**. Because your example is then wrong too.

Comment: But my positive example is "accggt" "gggatc" and those two strings are **different on every position**! And your code found this too, but unfortunately also a not different third string.

Comment: Yes, `accggt` and `gggatc` are different on every position. But `accggt` and `agctta` are not. So for your list of DNA strings in the question, the result should be `None`, right?

Comment: @Tobias I've updated my answer. Next time, please provide just a simpel example with the **input** of your function and the **output**.

Comment: I saw it, thanks a lot,  but the version before was closer. I have to be more clear: When I take my posted list, my desired output would be something like this list: [['accggt', 'agctta'] , ['gggatc', 'ccttgg']]..I'm very sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Ok, now where do you have problems? You've already described the algorithm you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dnaList = "accggt agctta gggatc gactta ccttgg".split( " " );

function getUniqueDnas( dna_list ){
  var result = [];
  for( var d1 in dna_list ){
    var isRepeat = false;
    var dna1 = dna_list[ d1 ];
    for( var d2 in dna_list ){
      var dna2 = dna_list[ d2 ];
      if( dna1 == dna2 ){
        isRepeat = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if( !isRepeat ) 
      result.push( dna1 );
  }
  return result;
}

var uniqueDnaList = getUniqueDnas( dnaList );
```